# Multiple Site Profiles Graphed Together

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, reputation-graph

On the profile page I can see my activity graph over time.  How can I see the reputation graph including my profile on other sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists. You can find it by visiting your network profile (linked at the top right corner of your profile page), and then viewing the "reputation" tab. However, the graph will only include sites where you've earned at least 200 reputation (so for you, it will currently not display anything as you don't have any qualifying sites yet).

Comment: It must be that I don't have enough reputation to be able to see that.  This is a feature that I will be looking forward to when I have gained enough reputation.  Thanks.